# Magento on MAMP

Tags: php, magento2, mamp-pro

I want to use Magento 2.x.x but the problem is that the php versions which this Magento(2.x.x) supports, doesn't match the php versions which [MAMP supports](https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/)

> Magento supports PHP 5.6.5, 7.0.2, 7.0.4 and 7.0.6 or later. Please
>   read Magento System Requirements.

---

I'm using MAMP Pro version 3.5 on Mac OSX El-Captain

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by setup brew php74 right now , then change the path in .zshrc or bashrc accordionists to what you use . then it worked with all the extensions.